# Get Geo Location details of Image

Tags: app-inventor

Is there any API / way to achieve the geo location details (lat, long) details of an image taken from a camera. When a user capture a picture from camera , i would like to get the lat , long position details of the captured image.

Comment: You mean like in the metadata of the image somewhere, or do you mean ascertaining it from the image content (probably impossible)?

Comment: metadata would also work, all i need is , if a user takes a new picture,i need to have the location details from where the picture was taken?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the metadata of a taken photo with App Inventor.

In **App Inventor** you can use the `location sensor` to get the lat and long coordinates.
After taking the image with the `camera` component, just read the current lat and long coordinates...

Comment: Hi Taifun, Thanks so , you suggest to capture the image and set the geo co ordinates by a button click. Can you share any code snippets to save the image in a MYSQL DB . I have seen a sample at http://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php , and is working perfectly fine here. But not sure how to share in a MYSQL DB ? Any inputs ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If the answer to the current question was helpful, see here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)...